# sqlite SUM result decimal gone

Tags: sqlite, sum, decimal, currency

Test Code :

```
> String x = "30000000000.222";
> String y = "20000000000.444"; 
> double x1 = Double.parseDouble(x);  
> double y1 = Double.parseDouble(y);
> 
> ContentValues vValue51 = new ContentValues();
> vValue51.put(DatabaseStructure.fTmpAttr_X3         , x1 );
> vDatabase.insertData(DatabaseStructure.cTblTemporary3, vValue51);

> ContentValues vValue61 = new ContentValues(); 
> vValue61.put(DatabaseStructure.fTmpAttr_X3  , y1 );
> vDatabase.insertData(DatabaseStructure.cTblTemporary3, vValue61);

> vDatabase.closeDatabase();
> 
> 
> 
> List<Map<String, String>> vListData2 = new
> ArrayList<Map<String,String>>(); String vQuerY32;
>           
> 
> vQuerY32 = "Select SUM(" + DatabaseStructure.fTmpAttr_X3 + " ) 'jik' " + 
>            "From " + DatabaseStructure.cTblTemporary3; 
> 
>           vDatabase = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
>           vListData2 = vDatabase.getListData(vQuerY32);
>           vDatabase.closeDatabase();

I tried many data type for column

> vQuery = "create table " + cTblTemporary3 +
>                "("+
>                fTmpAttr_ID3 + " integer primary key, " +
>                fTmpAttr_V3  + " DECIMAL(10,5), " +
>                fTmpAttr_W3  + " FLOAT , " +
>                fTmpAttr_X3  + " REAL, " +
>                fTmpAttr_Y3  + " DOUBLE PRECISION, " +
>                fTmpAttr_Z3  + " double " +
>                ")";       vSQL.execSQL(vQuery);
```

> > ======================getListDataFunction===========================================
>
> ```
>  public List<Map<String, String>> getListData(String vQuery)
> {
>
>   List<Map<String, String>> vListData = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
>
>   Cursor vCursor = getCursorData(vQuery);
>   int vLength = vCursor.getColumnCount();
>   String[] vFields = new String[vLength];
>
>   if (vCursor.getCount() > 0){
>       for (int i = 0; i < vLength; i++) 
>           vFields[i] = vCursor.getColumnName(i);
>
>       vCursor.moveToFirst();
>       while (!vCursor.isAfterLast()) {
>
>           Map<String, String> vMapData = new HashMap<String, String>();
>
>           for (int i = 0; i < vLength; i++) 
>               vMapData.put(vFields[i], vCursor.getString(i));
>
>           vListData.add(vMapData);
>
>           vCursor.moveToNext();
>       }
>   }
>
>   vCursor.close();
>   return vListData;       
> }
> ```

i Log the result

> Log.d("TEST", vListData2.get(0).get("jik"));

, the result is not 50000000000.666 but 5e+10, How i can get 50000000000.666 for the result? Please help this newbie :(

Comment: The problem is `Log`. What do you actually want to do with the result?

Comment: i want show the result on TextView

Comment: What makes you think you didn't get it? `Log` is rounding.

Comment: hooo sec, i tried show it, thanks master :>

Comment: when i show the result is 5e+10, i parse to double the result is 50000000000 :(

Comment: Why are you converting it to a string?